# Why layout_weight works different on differ devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have the xml, where image fills 60% of screen:

```
                   <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rl_images_layout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_marginBottom ="5dp">

                        <com.my.proj.view.ContentUpdatableImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_template1_image"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitStart" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivResizeIcon"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@id/iv_template1_image"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@id/iv_template1_image"
                            android:background="@drawable/btn_pinch" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivRotateIcon"
                            android:layout_width="55dp"
                            android:layout_height="55dp"
                            android:layout_alignRight="@id/iv_template1_image"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/iv_template1_image"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/btn_rotate"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                 </RelativeLayout>
                 <View 
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_weight="4" />
```

On one phone it works fine (LG P500), but on other device (HTC Desire HD) image fills only 40%. Any ideas?

Comment: What does a "View" look like?  It's an abstract class so as far as I can tell you shouldn't be able to just use it like that.  Off the top of my head, that seems like a likely thing.  Replace it with a `FrameLayout` and see if the rest of the view measures properly.

Answer (score 1):

You missed one thing.

If you are using `android:layout_weight` both the views should have the `fill_parent/match_parent` parameter as `layout_heigth` (if you want to spread the screen)

So change the `layout_heigth` in your first view to:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think its because of pixel density

please check this

[Android: screen support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: All values are set in dip(dp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    android:weightSum="100"  //for parent layout 

    android:layout_weight="60" // for first child //In your case relative layout

    android:layout_weight="40" //for second child //In your case view
```